# Modify Address Magento 2.1.3

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3

Magento is confusing. I want to modify how the address in the front end displays but I can't locate where it should be modified.

In the checkout page,the address fill out form shows in this order:

- Street Address
- Municipality
- Prefecture
- Zip Code
- Country

But I want it in japan address format:

- Country
- Zip Code
- Prefecture
- Municipality
- Street Address

[image]

Do you have any tips on how to find the page easily?

Comment: you are using one step chekout?

Comment: @PankajSharma Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the address formats are contained in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/config.xml look for some markup like this:

```
<default>
  <customer>
    <address_formats> 
     <text><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}
{{depend company}}{{var company}}{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}
{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}
{{var country}}
T: {{var telephone}}
{{depend fax}}F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}}]]></text>
    </address_templates>
  </customer>
</default>
```

or you can try this one also -

Go to:

```
`STORES->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration -> Address Templates`.
```

There you find the same code as in the XML file.

Comment: I think this path app/code/core/Mage/Customer/config.xml is different in Magento 2.1.3